# My activity is refreshing or restarting in after onactivity result, how to avoid that

Tags: android

I disable a button in my activity. I am calling my activity using startactivity android.media.provider.VIDEO_CAPTURE in on activity result I enable the button. In onactivityresult my activity restarts or resumes in android. Can anybody tell me how to avoid this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First onActivityResult() is called. Then, onResume() is called.

If you don't want to do anything after onActivityResult, then don't override onResume() method.